# Auto Switch between multiple forms with timer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have 5 Forms, 1 main form, and 4 forms I want them to switch between each other Automatically every couple of seconds (take turns, each form x seconds and switch to the next).

I have 2 forms so far switching between each other every 2 seconds.

```
void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!frm2.Focused)
            frm2.Focus();
        else
            frm3.Focus();
    }
 private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Timer mytimer = new Timer();
       mytimer.Tick += mytimer_Tick;
       mytimer.Interval = 2000;
       mytimer.Start();

    }
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Does that needs to be separate forms? Better idea would be to show different panels in same form itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crude format. But you will get the idea.

```
    private void HideAllForms()
    {
        frm1.Hide();
        frm2.Hide();
        frm3.Hide();
        frm4.Hide();
    }
    void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frmSrl == 1)
        {
            frmSrl++;
            HideAllForms();
            frm1.Show();
        }
        else if (frmSrl == 2)
        {
            frmSrl++;
            HideAllForms();
            frm2.Show();
        }
        else if (frmSrl == 3)
        {
            frmSrl++;
            HideAllForms();
            frm3.Show();
        }
        else if (frmSrl == 4)
        {
            frmSrl =1;
            HideAllForms();
            frm4.Show();
        }
        else
            frmSrl = 1;
    }
    int frmSrl = 1;
    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer mytimer = new Timer();
        mytimer.Tick += mytimer_Tick;
        mytimer.Interval = 2000;
        mytimer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: A stack of `else if` looks *ugly*, I suggest using an *array* of forms.